# using multiple resource dictionaries

Tags: silverlight

I have defined two resource dictionaries for controls which inherit from TextBox within my usercontrol like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="KeyBox.xaml" x:Key="KeyBox" ></ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="kTextBox.xaml" x:Key="kTextBox" ></ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I have created the styles in separate files with different target type:

```
<Style TargetType="b:kTextBox" >
```

Now when I create the controls using these resources only the style applied last actually gets applied, so if I remove the second the first works. There's something I am missing here to make use of two resources within the same usercontrol and I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your resource dictionaries like this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="KeyBox.xaml" x:Key="KeyBox" ></ResourceDictionary>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="kTextBox.xaml" x:Key="kTextBox" ></ResourceDictionary>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Note that unless you have a class named kTextBox, your Style wont work.

It's also worth mentioning that your control will only have one style applied at a time, and the last resource added to the dictionary will be applied. Therefore if you have a style defined in both of your dictionaries with the same key, the one from kTextBox.xaml will be applied.

Comment: I get this error when I do that > The attachable property 'MergedDictionaries' was not found in type 'ResourceDictionary

Comment: ok so TriggerPin what you suggested above works with a slight modification the references need to be defined in App.xaml rather than the usercontrol. I should add that the two styles as mentioned above are defined for separate classes.

Comment: just for future reference in the code above <UserControl.Resources> needs to be replaced with <Application.Resources>